# pass array of join to query in laravel

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, join

I have issue with my query. My sample  query is as below

```
$answers = DB::table('IC2017_AY')
        ->join('IC2017', 'IC2017_AY.UNITID', '=', 'IC2017.UNITID')
        ->join('SFA1617_P1', 'IC2017_AY.UNITID', '=', 'SFA1617_P1.UNITID')
        ->join('cost', 'IC2017_AY.UNITID', '=', 'cost.UNITID')
        ->join('gpa', 'IC2017_AY.UNITID', '=', 'gpa.UNITID')
        ->join('enrollment', 'IC2017_AY.UNITID', '=', 'enrollment.UNITID')
        ->join('major', 'IC2017_AY.UNITID', '=', 'major.UNITID')
        ->join('preference', 'IC2017_AY.UNITID', '=', 'preference.UNITID')
        ->select('IC2017_AY.TUITION2 as in_state_tuition','IC2017_AY.FEE2 as in_state_fee','IC2017_AY.TUITION3 as out_state_tuition','IC2017_AY.FEE3 as out_state_fee','IC2017_AY.CHG4AY3 as books_supplies','IC2017_AY.CHG6AY3 as other_expenses','IC2017.ROOMAMT as room_charge','IC2017.BOARDAMT as board_charge','IC2017.RMBRDAMT as combined_charge','SFA1617_P1.SCUGRAD as total_receiving','SFA1617_P1.SCUGFFN as full_time_receiving','SFA1617_P1.UAGRNTN as total_receiving_grant')
        ->where($where_data);
        ->get();
```

but now I want to pass the array of join because joins will be decided at run time something like this
below code is just the example.

```
$joins = [
['country', 'user_master.country_id', '=', 'country.country_id'],
['city', 'user_master.city_id', '=', 'city.city_id'],
['login_master', 'user_master.user_id', '=', 
'login_master.user_id'],
];
```

How  can I do this in laravel 5.8 
thanks in advance.!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `foreach loop` for example:

```
$joins = [
['country', 'user_master.country_id', '=', 'country.country_id'],
['city', 'user_master.city_id', '=', 'city.city_id'],
['login_master', 'user_master.user_id', '=', 
'login_master.user_id'],
];

$answers = DB::table('IC2017_AY')
        ->join('IC2017', 'IC2017_AY.UNITID', '=', 'IC2017.UNITID')
        ->join('SFA1617_P1', 'IC2017_AY.UNITID', '=', 'SFA1617_P1.UNITID')
        ->join('cost', 'IC2017_AY.UNITID', '=', 'cost.UNITID')
        ->join('gpa', 'IC2017_AY.UNITID', '=', 'gpa.UNITID')
        ->join('enrollment', 'IC2017_AY.UNITID', '=', 'enrollment.UNITID')
        ->join('major', 'IC2017_AY.UNITID', '=', 'major.UNITID')
        ->join('preference', 'IC2017_AY.UNITID', '=', 'preference.UNITID');

foreach($joins as $key=>$value){
$answer = $answer->join(implode(",",$value));
}

return $answer->select('IC2017_AY.TUITION2 as in_state_tuition','IC2017_AY.FEE2 as in_state_fee','IC2017_AY.TUITION3 as out_state_tuition','IC2017_AY.FEE3 as out_state_fee','IC2017_AY.CHG4AY3 as books_supplies','IC2017_AY.CHG6AY3 as other_expenses','IC2017.ROOMAMT as room_charge','IC2017.BOARDAMT as board_charge','IC2017.RMBRDAMT as combined_charge','SFA1617_P1.SCUGRAD as total_receiving','SFA1617_P1.SCUGFFN as full_time_receiving','SFA1617_P1.UAGRNTN as total_receiving_grant')
        ->where($where_data);
        ->get();
```